# New kernel version causes my second monitor not to work

Tags: nvidia, kernel, 22.04, multiple-monitors

I use Ubuntu 22.04.03, and I tried to update my kernel from v6.2.0-31-generic to v6.4.13

So, I downloaded:

```
linux-headers-6.4.13-060413_6.4.13-060413.202308301431_all.deb

linux-headers-6.4.13-060413-generic_6.4.13-060413.202308301431_amd64.deb

linux-image-unsigned-6.4.13-060413-generic_6.4.13-060413.202308301431_amd64.deb

linux-modules-6.4.13-060413-generic_6.4.13-060413.202308301431_amd64.deb
```

From `https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.4.13/`

Then in /Downloads run `sudo su` =>  `dpkg -i linux*.deb`

An the terminal trow me this error:

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
> linux-headers-6.4.13-060413-generic:
> linux-headers-6.4.13-060413-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.38);
> however:   Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.35-0ubuntu3.1.
>
> dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.4.13-060413-generic
> (--install):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Setting up
> linux-modules-6.4.13-060413-generic (6.4.13-060413.202308301431) ...
> Setting up linux-image-unsigned-6.4.13-060413-generic
> (6.4.13-060413.202308301431) ... Processing triggers for
> linux-image-unsigned-6.4.13-060413-generic
> (6.4.13-060413.202308301431) ... /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:  * dkms:
> running auto installation service for kernel 6.4.13-060413-generic
>
> Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...
>
> Building module: cleaning build area... unset ARCH; [ ! -h /usr/bin/cc
> ] && export CC=/usr/bin/gcc; env NV_VERBOSE=1 'make' -j12
> NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=6.4.13-060413-generic
> IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1
> SYSSRC=/lib/modules/6.4.13-060413-generic/build LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd
> CONFIG_X86_KERNEL_IBT= modules....(bad exit status: 2) ERROR (dkms
> apport): kernel package linux-headers-6.4.13-060413-generic is not
> supported Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel:
> 6.4.13-060413-generic (x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/470.199.02/build/make.log for more information.
> ...
> done.
>
> Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable
> partitions. Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot
> configuration. Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
> Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
> done.
>
> Errors were
> encountered while processing:  linux-headers-6.4.13-060413-generic

Anyways... reboot computer.

Second monitor doesn't work.

Both are connected via display port to my gpu. (nvidia)

Tried to reinstall official drivers, but nothing seems to change.

Settings -> Displays  / Does not even recognize the second monitor.

I would really appreciate your help, thank you very much.

Comment: I tried to start the pc via grub with the old version of the kernel (v6.2.0-31-generic) a version that previously had worked with my two monitors, but it didn't work...